# pass jqgrid value to an inputbox inside another div on dblClick

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

I have here a jqgrid. What I  want to do is when i double click a data inside the grid, it will display the amount data and the description in the another div. Note, they are in the same html page.

Here's js code:

```
$("#tblIncDed").jqGrid({ 
      data: '', 
    datatype: "local",     
    colNames:['Code','Description', 'Taxable','Amount'],
        colModel:[
      {name:'ded_code',width: 85},
            {name:'ded_desc'},
            {name:'taxable',width: 95},
            {name:'amount', formatter:'currency', align:'right',width: 85}
    ], 
    rowNum:20,                                              
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList:[20,50,100],        
    ppager: '#tblIncDedPager',
    viewrecords: true, 
    caption: "Details",
    ondblClickRow: function() {
      alert(parent.$(this).jqGrid('getCell',($(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')),'ded_desc'));//returns false
      var desc = $("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getCell',($("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')),'ded_desc');
      alert(desc);//also returns false
      parent.$("#description").text($("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getCell',($("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')),'ded_desc'));//displays false
      parent.$("#amntDed").text($("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getCell',($("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'amount')),'ded_desc'));//displays also false
      $("#editIncDed").dialog( "open" );

    }       
  });
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="editIncDed" title="Edit Earnings Details"> 
    <b><span id="description"></span></b> <br>
    Amount:
      <br><input class="numeric" type="text" id="amntDed" value = "" class="numeric"/>
</div>
```

I really don't know how to display the values to the other element of another div. this may sound simple to someone out there, but i just cant figure it out.

**NOTE**
I know that this code:
`alert('this is the description ' + $("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getCell',($("#tblIncDed").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')),'ded_desc'));`

alerts the description of the row that i selected, when i clicked a button inside the same div where my jqgrid is placed. I just want to get and display that value in an element from another div.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents).

For the ondblClickRow event you get "rowid, iRow, iCol, e". So call it with those params and then use them:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
alert('col is ' + iCol);
alert('row is ' + iRow);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but you code only gives me the index number of the column row and column that i clicked. I want to get the value of the amount and description when i double click a row and display it my input box and span.

Comment: once you have rowid and iCol, you can use getCell to get the value of the cell. The use $.val and $.text to set you the text of the textbox and span.